# How to use grouping feature in Excel pivot table function in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe.

| id | Score | Action_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S11 | 0.585366 | Not Traded |
| P555 | 0.457778 | Not Traded |
| B28 | 0.636154 | Not Traded |
| A859 | 0.000000 | Traded |
| P556 | 0.761905 | Not Traded |
| Y461 | 0.333333 | Not Traded |
| S121 | 0.444444 | Not Traded |
| K481 | 0.000000 | Traded |
| S122 | 1.000000 | Not Traded |
| R556 | 0.000000 | Traded |
| R627 | 0.602778 | Traded |

In excel using pivot table and grouping I was able to do this.

How to achieve this using pandas

[image]

And pivot table [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could create bins using `pd.cut`, then use `crosstab` to get the counts each each action flag. Finally, `assign` the row-wise totals to a new column "Grand_total":

```
out = pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['Score'], np.linspace(0,1,21), include_lowest=True), df['Action_flag']).assign(Grand_total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
Action_flag     Not Traded  Traded  Grand_total
Score                                          
(-0.001, 0.05]           0       3            3
(0.3, 0.35]              1       0            1
(0.4, 0.45]              1       0            1
(0.45, 0.5]              1       0            1
(0.55, 0.6]              1       0            1
(0.6, 0.65]              1       1            2
(0.75, 0.8]              1       0            1
(0.95, 1.0]              1       0            1
```

Comment: why linspace(0,1,21) starts with -0.001 instead of 0

Comment: @Shubh it doesn’t; but pd.cut with interval index is open from the lower bound for each bin, so it appears like that but it’s actually 0. It’s just notation. You could also do right=False.